# What is the good design pattern for connection pooling?

Tags: web-services, design-patterns, database-connection, connection-pooling

What is the good design pattern for implementing one connection (or generally resource) pool? For example, one tomcat server connects to one mysql server, and all the requests share a mysql connection pool on tomcat server. I have search for some time, some people proposed to use Singleton or put the initialization code inside some static block. But others said singleton is bad. So, what should be a right design pattern to use for connection pooling? Thanks.

Comment: 1. Consider using existing pooling frameworks, like apache dbcp pooling. Tomcat has build them in: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_%28DBCP%29_Configurations 2. The "Factory" pattern is usually used in cases when you do it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Object (Resource) Pool is a Design Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/object-pool-pattern.html).

There is not a single Connection pool in Tomcat, instead it allows you to [define multiple pools](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html).  You then control the scope and access to each pool via a [service provider](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#DriverManager,_the_service_provider_mechanism_and_memory_leaks) as either the global server, a service, an engine, a host or just a single [context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html).  The application looks up connection pool and the service provider ensures the defined rules are upheld.

However, your question it so open ended we cannot feasible suggest the most appropriate solution for you.

Answer (score 4):

FlyWeight Design pattern used for Connection Pooling . as stated by GOF "Facilitates the reuse of many fine grained objects, making the utilization of large numbers of objects more efficient."

Answer (score 0):

I prefer **singleton design pattern**.

It will create Instance single time and Used frequently.

for timely connection pooling `Singleton` it will easy and good.