# Pattern for JDNI datasource

Tags: java, tomcat, azure, jndi

I'm using a JNDI ressource in Tomcat8 for connecting to a MS-SQL database (Azure). Randomly I experience `Connection closed` exception, eventually preceeded by `Connection peer reset` events. When this happens, the service is dead (running into `Connection closed` for every request) and restarting the tomcat (redploying) is the only chance to get it up again.

On my way trying to solve this I double(triple)-checked every method for unclosed connections, I assure that every connection is opened as `try-with-ressource`.

Currently I'm trying to get a better understanding about JNDI ressources and the connection pooling, I'm asking what is the preferred pattern to implement a service class which is injected into other services. E.g. questions are

1. Where should the `DataSource` be allocated by calling `ctx.lookup()`? On method level or class scope? E.g. when using the hk2 `@Service` annotation it seems that a service is instantiated only once and not per request. Currently `ctx.lookup()` is invoced once (in the constructor) and the `DataSource` is stored in a class field and later on accessed by the methods using `this.dataSource`. Does this make sense ? Or should the `DataSource` be retrieved on every request (=method call)
2. How can I verify the execution of several options of the DataSource, e.g. `testOnBorrow` and `removeAbandoned` (see complete configuration below) are executed correctly? There is an option `logAbandoned` but I can not see anything in my logs. Where should this appear anyhow? Can I somehow specifiy a certain log level for the pool? I only found `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool`, but this class seems only to be called when creating the pool (at least this is the only moment when logs appear, even on level `FINEST`).
3. Are there general patterns which I'm not aware of?

Here my current configuration:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mssql"
          auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.XADataSource"
          driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
          username="***"
          password="***"
          url="jdbc:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433;database=***;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true"
          removeAbandonedTimeout="55"
          removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
          timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="34000"
          minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="55000"
          logAbandoned="true"
          validationQuery="SELECT 1"
          validationInterval="34000"
        />
```

Thx, gapvision

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gapvision, you can check this link -  [What is the good design pattern for connection pooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256758/what-is-the-good-design-pattern-for-connection-pooling)

Probably, you would want to go with the object pool pattern. 
Hope this helps !!

Comment: This is not an answer, add it as a comment!

Comment: I'm looking for the design pattern!

Comment: Updated my response. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm asking what is the preferred pattern to implement a service class which is injected into other services.

Try spring data. It is very helpful in organizing resources to access data.

Without spring, without tomcat built-in features, you indeed need create your own singletons to allocate DataSource or ConnectionPool.

Without spring(assuming you build web app for tomcat), you can add to web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
<description>H2DB</description>
<res-ref-name>jdbc/project1</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

And in context.xml of tomcat:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/project1" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"  url="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/project1"   username="sa" password="" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1"/>
```

And then you can lookup data source in each request:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/project1");
Connection conn = null;
try {
conn = ds.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO USERS (NAME) VALUES (?)");
ps.setString(1,name);
ps.executeUpdate();
response.getWriter().write("added user "+name);
response.getWriter().write("\n");
} finally {
if (conn!=null) { conn.close(); }
}
```

Or you can create a singleton class and lookup DataSource once , on start or lazy, as singletons do.

But better try spring data.

Comment: Hm seems not really to be an answer to my questions as it shows how to include a JNDI resource but not the best practice of it